# Python Tkinter - Can radio button values be floating point numbers?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm writing a program where I've to select 15 values out of 6 radio buttons each, and each value that should be returned is a floating point value. On using Tkinter Radiobutton:

```
r155 = Radiobutton(master,text=" ",variable=j, value=1.10)
```

It returns the value after ignoring the values after decimal point, here j.get() returns 1.

Similarly, for:

```
r144 = Radiobutton(master,text=" ",variable=i, value=0.91)
```

i.get() return 0. Is it possible to get floating point numbers?

Comment: Can't you just keep the value `int` and define a `dict` that will convert each `int` into desired `float`?

Comment: I've 15*6 option for selection and the Radio buttons are in a horizontal grid. Couldn't get it to work with dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your variables can take floating point values. However, for that, you need to define `i` and `j` to be `DoubleVar`s rather than `IntVar`s

Even though it is not shown, I believe that somewhere earlier than your radio button definitions you have the lines:

```
i = IntVar()
j = IntVar()
```

These must be changed to:

```
i = DoubleVar()
j = DoubleVar()
```

respectively.

Also, note that if your radio buttons belong to the same group, they should use the same variable (i.e., the argument `variable=i` should be used for both buttons):

Comment: @JishnuVijayan You are welcome. Please accept the answer, to make clear that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Done @JohanL, Also, as I've less reputation, my upvote isn't visible.